# the coefficiant before the sum of determinant $a_{p_kq_k}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to extend an example given from the textbook a little bit and not sure if I got the answer correct

**[Example]:** For the sum of the {principal minor with order of $k$} of a {$n$ by $n$ determinant} $S$:
$$S=\displaystyle\sum_{q_1 \lt q_2 \lt...\lt q_k}\begin{vmatrix}a_{q_1q_1}&a_{q_1q_2}&...&a_{q_1q_k}\\a_{q_2q_1}&a_{q_2q_2}&...&a_{q_2q_k}\\...\\a_{q_kq_1}&a_{q_kq_2}&...&a_{q_kq_k}\end{vmatrix}$$
where $q_1,\ q_2,\ ...,\ q_k$ is a possible combination from $1,\ 2,\ ...,\ n$. We can have:
$$S=\displaystyle\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{q_1=1}^n\sum_{q_2=1}^n...\sum_{q_k=1}^nA\left(\begin{matrix}q_1, q_2, ..., q_{k}\\q_1, q_2, ..., q_{k}\end{matrix}\right)$$

**[Question]:** If consider instead the determinant as
$$T=\displaystyle\sum_{\begin{matrix}p_1 \lt p_2 \lt...\lt p_k\\q_1 \lt q_2 \lt...\lt q_k\end{matrix}}\begin{vmatrix}a_{p_1q_1}&a_{p_1q_2}&...&a_{p_1q_k}\\a_{p_2q_1}&a_{p_2q_2}&...&a_{p_2q_k}\\...\\a_{p_kq_1}&a_{p_kq_2}&...&a_{p_kq_k}\end{vmatrix}$$
and then
$$T=\displaystyle[???]\sum_{p_1=1,q_1=1}^n\sum_{p_2=1,q_2=1}^n...\sum_{p_k=1,q_k=1}^nA\left(\begin{matrix}p_1, p_2, ..., p_{k}\\q_1, q_2, ..., q_{k}\end{matrix}\right)$$
What would be the coefficient [???] in front of the multisum symbol?

I thought that $[???] = \frac{1}{k!\cdot k!}$ because $p_k$ and $q_k$ can be independently selected but I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: There are indeed $k!\cdot k!$ summands that select the same $k$ rows and the same $k$ columns, so the factor is correct.

Comment: @user1551 I guessed "rewrite" should have been "consider instead", and maybe $T$ instead $S$ would have been a better choice. The OP should clarify this in an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4151489/edit).

Comment: @user1551, thanks for the clarification, I did not realize that when replacing the sign

Comment: @Christoph, thanks, would you mind to elaborate a little bit? I can sort of understand it but I can't form a detailed explanation on paper.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. For each $k$-element subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ there are $k!$ ways to write its elements in a $k$-tuple. For example $\{1,2,3\}$ can be obtained from $(1,2,3)$, $(1,3,2)$, $(2,1,3)$, $(2,3,1)$, $(3,1,2)$ and $(3,2,1)$. The multisum-expression hence has $k!\cdot k!$ distinct summands that correspond to fixed sets of rows $\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}$ and columns $\{q_1,\dots,q_k\}$.

Comment: @Christoph, ah, I see it now.... my brain was kind of stuck when going through the jumble of notations......